# django sitemap for static react routes (error : NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml/)

Tags: reactjs, django, sitemap

i want to implement sitemap for static react routes and I get this error:

Reverse for 'contact' not found. 'contact' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

[image: NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml]

I added a list of my react routes `REACT-ROUTES` in settings.py and append them to urlpatterns in the root urls.py file

**settings :**

```
   REACT_ROUTES = [
        'contact',
        'politique-de-confidentialite',
        'mentions-legales',
        'cookies',
        .
        .
    
    ]  
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'corsheaders',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.sitemaps',
        'rest_framework',
        .
        .
    ]
    
    SITE_ID = 1
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ess')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
    

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = basepath + '/app/static'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ess', 'static')]
```

**urls :**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemaps import  StaticViewSitemap

react_routes = getattr(settings, 'REACT_ROUTES', [])

sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap
}

urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml/', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    re_path(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),

]

for route in react_routes:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path('{}'.format(route), TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
    ]
```

**sitemaps.py :**

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse


class StaticViewSitemap(Sitemap):

    def items(self):
        return ['contact']
    
    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

I don't know what I am missing, please help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a `sitemap.xml` file inside my react build folder

then added in urlpatterns

```
path('sitemaps.xml/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sitemap.xml', content_type='text/xml'),
```